# Let $p\left(x\right)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $p\left(x\right)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients such that $p\left(m\right)-p\left(n\right)$ divides $m^2-n^2$ for all integers $m$ and $n$. If $p\left(0\right)=1$ and $p\left(1\right)=2$, find the largest possible value of $p\left(100\right)$.

I got the answer to be $10001$. Could someone confirm whether this answer is correct?

Comment: *How* did you get your answer?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is correct.

- $p(100) - 1 = p(100) - p(0) \;\mid\; 100^2 - 0^2 = 10000$ 
  $\implies |p(100) - 1| \le 100^2$ $\implies p(100) \le 100^2 + 1 = 10001\,$, so $10001$ is an upper bound.
- $p(x)=x^2+1$ satisfies $p(0)=1$, $p(1)=2$, $\require{cancel} p(m)-p(n) = (m^2+\cancel{1})-(n^2+\cancel{1})$ $\mid\; m^2 - n^2$, and $p(100) = 100^2 + 1 = 10001$, so the upper bound is attained, therefore $10001$ is the maximum.

This holds true under the weaker condition that $p(k)$ must be an integer for all integer $k$, even if the coefficients of $p(x)$ are not required to be integers themselves.